# Как сделать задний фон у заголовка?

Tags: html, css

Задача следующая: есть задний фон и маленький заголовок. Нужно сделать так, чтобы надпись была по центру, а задний фон делал отступы от неё (15px, например).
[image: Вот образец]

В данном случае заголовок-MY LATEST WORK. Как Вы видите у картинки на заднем плане есть отступы от надписи, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой фон у заголовка можно сделать с помощью псевдоэлементов `:before` и `:after`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 33px;
}

h1:after {
  content: 'My latest work';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

h1:before {
  content: 'My latest work';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: calc(-100% - 20px);
  
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

h1:after,
h1:before {
  background-color: lightgray;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -moz-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-background-size: 3px 3px;
  -moz-background-size: 3px 3px;
  background-size: 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<h1>My latest work</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

вот так?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

span {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>MY LATEST WORK</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.subject {
 display: flex;
 height: 50px;
 align-items: center;
 color: gray;
}

.subject::after, .subject::before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 0 2px, currentcolor 2px 4px);
}

.subject span {
 flex-shrink: 0;
 margin: 0 30px;
 font-weight: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="subject">
 <span>MY LATEST WORKS</span>
</div>
```

Сделал с помощью `flex`'ов.

---

Отступы задаются от `span` (`margin`).

Цвет задаётся от класса `.subject` (`color`).

---

В основе лежит флекс контейнер, в котором находятся 3 элемента: 2 псевдоэлемента и один `span` . Псевдоэлементы делят между собой всю ширину контейнера и дают место под текст. Текст в свою очередь использует `flex-shrink: 0` , что не даёт блоку текста сжиматься из-за псевдоэлементов.

---

Не знаю почему такое поведение у градиента, он неравномерный и выглядит не точно как на картинке, но в любом случае делался как пример.